# How much worse is querying custom fields compared to custom taxonomies, quantitatively

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, query-posts

OK, I know (because i've read it many times) why custom fields is less efficient than custom taxonomies when it comes to querying/filtering posts, but just how inefficient is it by comparison? I'd love some researched quantitative statistics to back this up.

What sort of number of posts and custom fields are we talking about before my website collapses?

Comment: I should note, that the custom field set up I am using only allows defined values to choose from. That is, the values are set in place and generally won't be added to. Having said that some custom fields have 800 values.

Comment: The only real answer will come from you doing tests with your own data on your own hardware with your own configuration.

Comment: @Milo I think that would do as an answer, maybe with a bit more explanation :)

Comment: How would I test this? What variables would I need to measure?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as non constructive as the user is looking for concrete numbers. It is impossible to test due the large amount of factors involved, and the fact that almost no one has such large local installs to test this on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble with meta queries is they require an additional join *per filter*. Say you have a property site, and you're searching by location, rooms and price. That's three joins. If you were using taxonomies, just two (`terms` and `term_taxonomy`) - no matter how many  filters.

The other reason taxonomies tend to beat meta queries is their db schema. They're well indexed and optimised for searching - the meta table, whilst indexed on meta keys, has a value field that's large text - start querying on that bad boy (especially `LIKE` statements) and MySQL will have to take a breath or two.

Having said all that, meta queries have their place and can be extremely useful (with caution). And to be honest, unless you've got **thousands** of posts, or you're applying several meta queries, the difference will probably be negligible.

Comment: Thanks, like everything else I've read your answer makes complete sense as to why. But I'm really looking for some real world examples backed up by some measurable quantitative numbers that supports this poor performance comparison. Everyone says what you're saying but I've yet to see ANY evidence of it.

Comment: @Pete The only way you'll get measurable comparisons is to provide an exact scenario - there are too many unknown variables to conclusively say X is better than Y.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I'd like to see anyone's example of testing where they've demonstrated a significant, and measurable, difference. I've searched high and low and not found a single example (with quantitative data) showing what everyone is theoretically telling me. It would be great if there was someone out there that could trial several different scenarios to show evidence of this CF Vs CT issue.

Comment: But their example will be useless unless it closely matches your requirements - can you briefly explain to me what you're intending to achieve/implement?

Comment: I'm not asking in regard to my specific situation. I'm merely asking for reliable evidence to backup what is being said. Does the evidence support the theory?

Comment: For example, we could test querying/filtering 100 CFs through 10,000 posts compared to filtering 100 CTs through 10,000 posts and measure the outcomes. We could filter 1000 CFs through 10,000 posts and compare that to 1000 CTs filtered through 10,000 posts. Yes, I know there are more factors than those that will determine the performance BUT it's a start, and maybe something to further refine and change the variables etc. That's just 2 scenarios, other variables would be hosting factors, php version, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but these tests are pointless - it's like benchmarking two cars based on their 0 - 60, but you plan to use them to tow a bus. The metrics are only valuable when they're based on what you're intending to do with them.

Comment: Sorry but you've just made my exact point. If we can see results based on XYZ criteria that will allow us to extrapolate to our own situation (to varying degrees), that's how science works.

Comment: See this question here... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190218/querying-by-taxonomy-vs-querying-by-custom-fields-speed-comparison. The best answer given is "use what logically works for the data". But without ANY data then how can we even begin to make an educated guess. It's got to start somewhere.

Comment: Okay, so what do want? Generic tests? Why not run your own? If you need help, better to re-edit your question.

Comment: "Okay, so what do want?" I think you know what I want. "Why not run your own?". I don't know how nor have the resources. I think my question is correct for what i'm looking for. I have specifically included the word "quantitatively". Your answers have no quantitative element to them.

Comment: No, I don't know what you want! You're asking for tests & benchmarks, but won't give a scenario! I'm sorry I can't be more quantitative for you.

Comment: I think this discussion has reached it's usefulness for this topic. My question and above comments make clear my question.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Lb6Gh.gif

Comment: http://memesvault.com/wp-content/uploads/Spiderman-Meme-Thread-1.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jWsDYjO.png

Comment: @Pete Looking at this answer, and large amount of comments to his answer and your question, this really is a lack of interest to test this yourself. I really do not think anyone of us has such a large local install to test this for you. This whole exercise is really pointless and worthless testing this on a small local install, and it is also pointless for us spending days setting up such a huge local install to test this. You really need to take in account nesting, hierarchy, server hardware etc etc etc. I'm close voting this as non constructive

Comment: "this really is a lack of interest to test this yourself" No, you're wrong, I don't think you can judge my "interest", that's subjective and not part of answering my question. like I said above... "I don't know how nor have the resources". My question never asked any one to do any work for me. I was merely asking if there is any evidence you could link me to.

Comment: Pete, I see where you're coming from with the point "without ANY data then how can we even begin to make an educated guess" - what I'm asking is, at least initially, just explain what you want e.g. a properties system filtered by X attributes, an online shop with many-to-many relations. *Then* you start thinking about schemas to implement the functionality, and *then* you can start comparing which ones perform best.